# Meaning of new[] { } in c#

Tags: c#

What is the meaning in this code where it reads "new[] {}" ?

```
public Cube(Game game) : base(game)
{
    vertices = Buffer.Vertex.New(
        game.GraphicsDevice,
        new[]
            {
                new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f), Color.OrangeRed),
                new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), Color.OrangeRed),
            });
}
```

Comment: It's an example of object initialization.  It's declaring a new array of `VertexPositionColor` with a length of 2 and initializing the 2 elements by the call to `new VertexPositionColor`.

Comment: See: [Object and Collection Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initializing an Array of Structs in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309496/initializing-an-array-of-structs-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just creating an implicity typed array, in your code it is a VertexPositionColor[] with two elements.