# Constant array of constant objects in C#

Tags: c#, constants

I am aware that in C# const can only be initialized at compile time. Which is related to what I am trying to do.

My objective is to write *a constant array of constant objects* in C#. How can I do that?

In order to explain my self, allow me to insert some code in C++ (I wrote some code some time ago) that explains what I am trying to do.

(In C++)

```
struct FD{
 string name; 
 double CE[2]; 
};

const FD models[2]={
     {"one",{2.0,1.0}},
     {"two",{3.0,4.0}}
};
```

Seems very simple, right? How can I do something like this in C#?

---

EDIT: (Attempted answer)

I found that you can do something like this in C#

```
 struct FD
    {
        public string name;
        public double[] CE;
    }
 static readonly FD[] models= new[]
   {
     new FD(){name="one" , CE= new double[]{1.0,2.0 } },
     new FD(){name="two", CE= new double[]{3.0,4.0}}         
   };
```

I wonder if this could be a good way to achieve my objective?

Comment: The closest would probably be a [readonly](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly) [ReadOnlyCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms132474.aspx) of immutable structs/classes. But that's runtime and not compile time.

Comment: @Corak I found something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/309540/4451521 but it seems that is done on the heap not the stack and well it is not constant

Comment: @KansaiRobot - yes, that's still fully mutable. You can try `struct FD { public FD(string name, IEnumerable<double> ce) { Name = name; CE = new ReadOnlyCollection<double>(new List<double>(ce)); } private readonly string Name; private readonly IReadOnlyList<double> CE; }` -- but with that you can't restrict `CE` to only have exaclty two items.

Comment: @Corak Thanks. Could you take a look at my edit?

Comment: In your code, the instances of `FD` are fully mutable (try `models[0].name = "three";`. and the contents of the array `models` can also be changed freely (try `models[0] = new FD[...]`). -- *only* re-assigning a completely different array to the variable `models` is prohibited.

Comment: Maybe it helps if you explain why you need this? Could be possible that there is another solution.

Comment: @royalTS in the program there are values that are constant through the application (and they have a structure). These values are going to be constantly compared with data that is dynamically produced

Comment: ... btw. in my suggestion of how to implement `FD`, the fields `Name` and `CE` should of course be **public**...

Comment: @Corak I am trying your suggestion. how do you initialize FD with your implementation?...Oh..I got it :)

Comment: @KansaiRobot - `new FD("one", new[] { 1.0, 2.0 })` -- or the complete `static readonly IReadOnlyList<FD> models = new ReadOnlyCollection<FD>(new List<FD> { new FD("one", new[] { 1.0, 2.0 }), new FD("two", new[] { 3.0, 4.0 }) });`

Comment: @Corak I tried it with the public and you can not change name, but you can change the content of model[0] with a new element. I will try a little more and if not that seems good enough

Comment: @KansaiRobot - Use `readonly IReadOnlyList<FD> models = new ReadOnlyCollection<FD>([...]);` as shown above. Then modifying `models` should not be allowed.

Comment: Just some light reading - [mutable structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil)

Comment: (Even less related/welcoming) - I don't think any language allocates process wide constants on the stack... I'm really not sure why you are concerned about " that is done on the heap not the stack"...

Comment: @KansaiRobot Would it then be possible to create a public static comparison method which has the constant values only internally?

Comment: @royalTS maybe, but it lacks elegance. The idea is to have the values in an array of structures so that the values are completely separated from other code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end thanks to users Corak and Freggar I could come with something like this. (I suppose that model3 is the answer

Structs

```
 struct FD
    {
        public string name;
        public double[] CE;
    }

    struct FD2
    {
        public FD2(string name, IEnumerable<double>ce)
        {
            Name = name;
            CE = new ReadOnlyCollection<double>(new List<double>(ce));
        }
        public readonly string Name;   
        public readonly IReadOnlyList<double> CE;
    }
```

and the lists

```
 //This solution does not give the entire constant structure as name and FD[0] can be changed
        static readonly FD[] models= new[]
          {
              new FD(){name="one" , CE= new double[]{1.0,2.0 } },
              new FD(){name="two", CE= new double[]{3.0,4.0}}

          };

        //Here name can not be changed but models2[0] can be
        static readonly FD2[] models2 = new[]
        {
            new FD2("one",new double[]{1.0,2.0 }),
            new FD2("two", new double[]{3.0,4.0 })
        };

        //This is the best solution
        static readonly IReadOnlyList<FD2> models3 = new ReadOnlyCollection<FD2>(new[] {
            new FD2("one",new double[]{1.0,2.0 }),
            new FD2("two", new double[]{3.0,4.0 })
        }
        );

        //This is also a good solution but models4[0].CE[0] can be changed
        static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<FD> models4 = new ReadOnlyCollection<FD>(new[]
        {
             new FD(){name="one" , CE= new double[]{1.0,2.0 }},
             new FD(){name="two", CE= new double[]{3.0,4.0}}
        });
```

I guess models3 gives a good implementation to what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly in C# you cannot define arrays or structures as `const` since the constructor can have runtime logic and therefore has to be executed at runtime. Your proposed solution is almost what you want, you just need a `ReadonlyCollection<FD>` to encapsulate your Array:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<FD> models = new ReadOnlyCollection<FD>(new[]
{
    new FD(){name="one" , CE= new double[]{1.0,2.0 } },
    new FD(){name="two", CE= new double[]{3.0,4.0}}
});
```

Now you cannot change the reference of models (`readonly`) nor can you change the contents of it (`ReadonlyCollection`). You also cannot change any members of the `FD` instances since `FD` is a `struct` and the `ReadonlyCollection` creates another layer of indirection, basically copying your struct:

```
models = new ReadOnlyCollection<FD>(new FD[] { }); // Error CS0198  A static readonly field cannot be assigned to
models[0] = new FD(); // Error CS0200  indexer  is read only
models[0].name = "testname"; // Error CS1612  Cannot modify the return value
```

---

**EDIT :** I overlooked something, you can still change the array:

```
 models[0].CE[0] = 1; // compiles just fine
```

If possible you want to make `CE`readonly too, but I'm not sure if your API allows that

Comment: you forgot to make `CE` immutable.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov oh damn I overlooked that completely, hmm this makes it not that easy

Answer (score 1):

Thinking outside the box :P

Others are providing you with great ideas but if you want to have truly const 4 values then you could just:

```
    const double FD_one_0 = 2.0;
    const double FD_one_1 = 1.0;
    const double FD_two_0 = 3.0;
    const double FD_two_1 = 4.0;
```